# Create SCRAM user credentials in Kafka Cluster with Spring Boot Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka and trying to implement the following command line code with latest spring kafka version but still have no clue apart from using `KafkaConfig` class for it.

```
kafka-configs --zookeeper zookeeper-1:22181 --alter --add-config \
'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=4096,password=password],SCRAM-SHA-512=[iterations=4096,password=password]' \
--entity-type users --entity-name metricsreporter
```

Kindly help as i am kind of stuck.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can use ProcessBuilder to run the exact same shell command. You don't need to do it all "from Java"

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have kafka  running inside docker on kubernetes cluster. How to connect to it from java kafka client with ```ProcessBuilder``` is main issue.